# Proper notation for a function with a domain of binary numbers? Is it a boolean function?

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation, boolean-algebra

I don't really know how to formulate my question but I give it a try.

Suppose I want to write a function where the domain is a binary number and the range is either $0$ or $1$:
$$
f:\{0,1\}^2\rightarrow \{0,1\} \tag 1
$$

**My problem:**
*I think $(1)$ is wrong because of the following:*

I want the domain to be a binary number $x_1 x_0$, where $x_i\in \{0,1\}$. So $x_1 x_0$ can assign the values:
\begin{align}
x_1 x_0 &= 00 \tag 2\\
x_1 x_0 &= 01 \tag 3\\ 
x_1 x_0 &= 10 \tag 4\\
x_1 x_0 &= 11 \tag 5
\end{align}
So for $f(x_1x_0)$ I have, for instance, $f(00)=0$, $f(01)=0$, $f(11)=1$ etc, etc.

But in $(1)$ I have the Cartesian product which by definition is:
\begin{align}
\{0,1\}^2 = \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} = \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\} \tag 6
\end{align}
**I.e. between each component there is a COMMA, but in $(2)-(5)$ where are no commas**.

So isn't $(1)$ wrong?
However, the following doesn't look right either:
$$
f:\{x_1x_0\}^2\rightarrow \{0,1\}\qquad \tag 7
$$

What is the correct notation?

[At Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_function) I found boolean functions, but they use commas between the components (in the domain) which isn't a binary number $x_1x_0$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to standard terminology, $11100101$ is still a binary number, but it is not in $\{0, 1\}^2$.

Comment: Practically there's no difference between a pair $(x_1,x_0)$ and a string $x_1x_0.$

Answer (score 1):

Well you can identify cartesian product with a string. Probably the concept that you are looking is for the **free monoid with the operation of concatenation**. In particular, using the alphabet $\Sigma =\{0,1\}$ you can form **all** finite strings of an alphabet in the set $$\Sigma ^*=\bigcup _{i=0}^{\infty} \Sigma ^i,$$
where $\Sigma ^i$ means all of the strings of length $i$ and the star corresponds to the operation of **kleene star.** You can make this precise by defining the function $$|\cdot |:\Sigma ^*\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$ that describes the length of a string(using a recursive definition given by the definition of concatenation). So, in particular you would like to construct the set $$\{0,1\} ^2=\{x\in \{0,1\}^*:|x|=2\}.$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Does $\{0,1\} ^2=\{x\in \{0,1\}^*:|x|=2\}$ mean we can write $\{0,1\}^*=\bigcup _{i=0}^{2} \{0,1\} ^?$? And does this notation mean $$
\{0,1\}^*=\bigcup _{i=0}^{2} \{0,1\} ^i=\{0,1\} \bigcup \{0,1\} = \{0,1\} \quad ?
$$

Comment: Hi, no. It means that you can concatenate symbols any time you want. So
$\{0,1\}^*=\{\lambda,0,1,00,01,10,11,000,001,010,011,100,\cdots\}$ but $\{ x\in \{0,1\}^*:|x|=2\}=\{00,01,10,11\}$ because those are the words in the big set that have length 2.